# SQL SELECT ALL of 2 columns, multiply by another column from Table 1 and INSERT in Table 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the below:

```
Customer_Table
ID  |   CustomerID     Balance      Multiplying_Factor
1   |   739         |   500     |   8
2   |   3049        |   230     |   6
3   |   591         |   1050    |   10
4   |   035         |   85      |   5
```

- I need to select all `CustomerID` whose `Balance is > 100`.
- Then with matching CustomerID and `Balance` pair selected, I will divide each `Balance` by "2" and the answer (new value) will now be referred to as `Stake` to use in the Trade_Table
- This `Stake` will now be multiplied by the corresponding value in the `Multiplying_Factor` column in the `Customer_Table` for each `CustomerID`. The answer (new value) will be referred to as `Turnover` to be used in the `Trade_Table`
- Now, if we subtract `Stake` from `Turnover` we will get `ROI` to be used in the `Trade_Table`

NEXT STEP [ Inserting values above into Trade_Table]

For each Row Inserted in the `Trade_Table`, we will auto-generate UNIQUE values for the following column:

** `TradeID` (Random 6 digits)

```
Trade_Table
ID  |   CustomerID      Stake       Turnover    ROI         Status          TradeID         Timestamp
1   |   739         |   250     |   2000    |   1750    |   Pending     |   750392      |   Currenttimestamp
2   |   3049        |   115     |   690     |   575     |   Pending     |   127543      |   Currenttimestamp
3   |   591         |   525     |   5250    |   4725    |   Pending     |   009765      |   Currenttimestamp
```

FURTHER STEP

Once the above is achieved, I will like to UPDATE the `Balance` for each `CustomerID` in the `Customer_Table`.
What SQL statement to `SET Balance=Stake` for each `CustomerID` like we have above and also `SET Multiplying_Factor=new_factor`?

**`new_factor` will be an auto-generated `value >5 but <12` for each row

I cannot statement various sources I have searched but trust me, this exceed my basic SQL knowledge since it has to do with creating new values on the fly. I can handle most PHP part of the rest of the codes but Advanced SQL is not my thing at the moment. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

> So far, this is what I have written out:

```
    require("dbconnection.php"); // Require DB Details and Connection details

$conn->set_charset("utf8");// Set characters to UTF8

$sql = "SELECT CustomerID, Balance, Multiplying_Factor FROM Customer_Table WHERE Balance > 100";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$GLOBALS['count'] = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

echo "<table id=\"t01\">
  <tr>
    <th>Customer ID</th>
    <th>Balance</th> 
    <th>Stake</th> 
    <th>Factor</th> 
    <th>Turnover</th> 
    <th>ROI</th>
  </tr>";
  // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $GLOBALS['Stake'] = $row["Balance"] / 2;
        $GLOBALS['CustomerID'] = $row["CustomerID"];
        $GLOBALS['Balance'] = $row["Balance"];
        $GLOBALS['Multiplying_Factor'] = $row["Multiplying_Factor"];
        $GLOBALS['Turnover'] = $Stake * $Multiplying_Factor;
        $GLOBALS['ROI'] = $Turnover - $Stake;
  echo "<tr class=\"GridItems\">
    <td>$CustomerID</td>
    <td>$Balance</td>
    <td>$Stake</td>
    <td>$Multiplying_Factor</td>
    <td>$Turnover</td>
    <td>$ROI</td></tr>";
    }
  echo "</table>";
  }
```

Now, I can get each row on a table with the new values that I was looking for on the fly (Though I don't need them on a table, I am just creating a visual impression).

My main issue now is how to INSERT in to the Trade_Table for each CustomerID from the resultset above.

My INSERT statment:

```
$Insert = "INSERT into Trade_Table (`CustomerID`, `Stake`, `Turnover`, `ROI`) VALUES ('$CustomerID[$i]', '$Stake[$i]', '$Turnover[$i]', '$ROI[$i]')";
$result = $conn->query($Insert);
```

But this will only insert one row and not all. How do I get this done? How do I get multiple corresponding data to insert at once. I have tried the "for each" statement but I can't get it right.

Comment: That isnt a question. That is do this job for me.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for responding. However, it is of course a question because what I want to do is very complex. It is just the SQL statement that's my drawback. I can handle most of the PHP part. The SQL is the headway for me to proceed with my other codes. Thanks again for responding.

Comment: I understand, but look at your first question `I need to select all CustomerID whose Balance is > 100.` that is so basic that tell you haven't try anything. And this isn't a free code service. We expect at least you try something and show your effort.

Comment: Thanks @Aureate for the edit.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza SELECT CustomerID, Balance FROM Customer_Table WHERE Balance > 100 is what you are asking. Yes, this is basic but I only stated the whole requirement and where I am coming from to be able to achieve the multiplications and additions that will be required on the fly. I was only trying to be as plain as possible for all to understand. And yes, I know basic SQL queries. But when it's complex, I struggle.

Comment: Then you are wasting our time asking something you already know how to do. Simplify your question to just the part you don't know. Think about it. If the question is more specific you will get better answers. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sorry, I was away. Let me review the parts you asked me to do and see how specific I can be.

Comment: Hi, everyone. I am sorry that I made my first post without posting what I have tried to date. I have now done this. You can see from my edited post above. I understand asking such basking questions has cost me losing my reputation points. Now that I have provided the required efforts that I have made, can I get my reputation back? I need your help now on the multiple INSERT statement. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to help you from what I understand in your question. Before that:

`I'm not a PhP guy -so no help there`

`I can help you with framing the MySQL query alone`

My understanding is that:

`You want to manipulate the values in the 'customer' table and insert them into the 'trade' table`

`After the insert, you want to update the 'customer' table with the values from 'trade' table`

With this as requirement, here's what you can do.

First I create your two tables:
I create table 'customer' with your values.

```
mysql> select * from customer;
+------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| ID   | customerID | Balance | Multiplying_Factor |
+------+------------+---------+--------------------+
|    1 |        739 |     500 |                  8 |
|    2 |       3049 |     230 |                  6 |
|    3 |        591 |    1050 |                 10 |
|    4 |         35 |      85 |                  5 |
+------+------------+---------+--------------------+
```

I create table 'trade'. I don't include the columns 'Status / TradeID/ Timestamp' since you haven't specified anything about how these are filled. Currently the table is empty so I just describe it.

```
mysql> desc trade;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID         | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| customerID | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Stake      | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Turnover   | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ROI        | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I write the SELECT query you need to manipulate the values in 'customer' table to GET Stake / Turnover / ROI

```
mysql> select ID, customerID, (Balance/2) as Stake,     
((Balance/2)*Multiplying_Factor) as Turnover, 
(((Balance/2)*Multiplying_Factor)-(Balance/2)) as ROI from customer 
where Balance>100;
+------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| ID   | customerID | Stake    | Turnover  | ROI       |
+------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 |        739 | 250.0000 | 2000.0000 | 1750.0000 |
|    2 |       3049 | 115.0000 |  690.0000 |  575.0000 |
|    3 |        591 | 525.0000 | 5250.0000 | 4725.0000 |
+------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now to do the INSERT:

```
insert into trade select ID, customerID, (Balance/2), 
((Balance/2)*Multiplying_Factor), (((Balance/2)*Multiplying_Factor)-
(Balance/2)) from customer where Balance>100;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

A 'SELECT' from the 'trade' table, shows your expected result in your question:

```
mysql> select * from trade;
+------+------------+-------+----------+------+
| ID   | customerID | Stake | Turnover | ROI  |
+------+------------+-------+----------+------+
|    1 |        739 |   250 |     2000 | 1750 |
|    2 |       3049 |   115 |      690 |  575 |
|    3 |        591 |   525 |     5250 | 4725 |
+------+------------+-------+----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now for the UPDATE query:

```
mysql> update customer join trade using(customerID) set Balance=Stake;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from customer;
+------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| ID   | customerID | Balance | Multiplying_Factor |
+------+------------+---------+--------------------+
|    1 |        739 |     250 |                  8 |
|    2 |       3049 |     115 |                  6 |
|    3 |        591 |     525 |                 10 |
|    4 |         35 |      85 |                  5 |
+------+------------+---------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which updates your 'Balance' column in 'customer' table. I'm not writing the update query for 'multiplying_factor' because there is no good explanation about this field "new_factor" you mention in your post.

I hope this helps you out

Comment: @Krishnakumar...Thanks a whole lot for your help. It has given me a head way to be honest with you. You are a life saver. However,  I have this INSERT Query       $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT into trade select id, CustomerID, (Balance/2), 
((Balance/2)*Multiplying_Factor), (((Balance/2)*Multiplying_Factor)-
(Balance/2)) from Customer_Table where Balance>100");

When run once, it does insert the rows in the trade table. But on second run, nothing is inserted only old rows remain. Maybe I am doing something wrong as each CustomerID can have multiple rows.

Comment: @EricChurchill : Glad it was able to give you an head start... I didn't know that each customer_ID can have multiple rows.. in that case.. it is not unique...
If the ID column of your table is under auto-increment or a primary key.. then using "select id, customerID..." won't work the 2nd time...

Comment: It's difficult to answer without knowing the description & relation between customer and trade tables properly.. like which is the primary key etc... Because I just came to know that 'customerID' is not unique.. which means the update query I have suggested might be wrong...

Comment: the ID column on each table is set to AUTO-INCREMENT. For the customer table, the CustomerID is the Unique Key while for the trade table, the TradeID will be the Unique KEY. Though I havent mentioned how this will be auto-generated randomly with PHP for each inserted row, I have made it UNIQUE because no two trade rows will be same. All trades are UNIQUE. A CustomerID can have many rows inserted in the trade table. And Yes, the UPDATE query is also wrong. But we can fix that once we sort the multiple insert row for each CustomerID.

Comment: Since the ID column is auto-increment.. I suggest you do this:

Comment: do what, please? I cannot see the rest part of your comment.

Comment: insert into trade (customerID,Stake,Turnover,ROI) select customerID, (Balance/2), ((Balance/2)*Multiplying_Factor), (((Balance/2)*Multiplying_Factor)-(Balance/2)) from customer where Balance>100;

You need to have all the columns of trade and their values.. I use 4 because I created the table with just 4 columns :)

Comment: The INSERT several rows works now for same CustomerID. After a few tests, I see that one issue springs up with the UPDATE query. Now, if a CustomerID has like 10 rows in the Trade table, when UPDATE customer table, which of the "Stake" rows in the trade table will be used to UPDATE the "Balance" in the customer table? Obviously, what we would want in this scenario is for the most recent Stake row entered in the trade table would be used to update the current balance of the CustomerID in the customer table. How then do we get latest INSERTED row for all CustomerID in the trade?